# Apple Notary and Go binaries

Tags: macos, go

One of the requirements for Apple Notary approval is to have an SDK >= 10.9. The go compiler (provided at golang.org) creates binary with an SDK inside of 10.7.

How does one create a Go-based application that would satisfy the new Apple Notary requirements?

```
 ~/gohelloworld (master) ) otool -l main | tail -n4
      cmd LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX
  cmdsize 16
  version 10.7
      sdk 10.7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One potential solution would be to modify the go compiler source code, in ...link/internal/ld/macho.go, to set different digits in the link header.

Documented a go issue there:
  https://github.com/golang/go/issues/30488